# Displaying MySQL Records in a HTML Table. What fails?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am having a Problem Displaying MySQL Records in a HTML Table

Here is the code:

> ```
>     <html>
> <head>
> </head>
> <body>
> <?php
>                         $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
>                         if (!con) {
>                         die ("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
>                         }
>
>                         mysql_select_db ("regform", $con);
>
>                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
>                         $myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
>                       echo 'test';    
>                         echo "<table border = '1'>
>
>                         <tr>
>                         <th>Name</th>
>                         <th>Lastname</th>
>                         <th>Phone</th>
>                         <th>Email</th>
>                         <th>Comment</th>
>                         </tr>";
>
>                         while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
>                         echo "<tr>";
>                         echo "<td>" . $record['Name'] . "</td>";
>                         echo "<td>" . $record['Lastname'] . "</td>";
>                         echo "<td>" . $record['Phone'] . "</td>";
>                         echo "<td>" . $record['Email'] . "</td>";
>                         echo "<td>" . $record['Comment'] . "</td>";
>                         echo "</tr>";
>
>                         }
>
>                         echo "</table>";
>
>                         mysql_close ($con);
>
>                         ?>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

**i get this on the browser:**

> Name Lastname Phone Email Comment "; while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) { echo ""; echo "" . $record['Name'] . ""; echo "" . $record['Lastname'] . ""; echo "" . $record['Phone'] . ""; echo "" . $record['Email'] . ""; echo "" . $record['Comment'] . ""; echo ""; } echo ""; mysql_close ($con); ?>

Comment: It's a `.html` page, right? Rename it to `.php`

Comment: Looks like your PHP isn't being parsed. Does the file end in .php? Are you getting any errors? Can you run a PHP page with just `<?php phpinfo() ?>`?

Comment: Sounds like your server doesn't have PHP installed or set-up.

Comment: what web server are you running? and do you have the correct modules installed (if you are running apache do you have mod-php)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: Yeah renamed it to .php and it worked. Now i get new error that i'll try to fix

Notice: Use of undefined constant con - assumed 'con' in D:\xampp\htdocs\project2\thankyou.php on line 7
test
Notice: Undefined index: Name in on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: Name in on line 28

Comment: if the table name in the database is not `Name` (notice the capital 'N') then change it to how it is in the database.. also it's `$con` not `con`. I suggest learning more of the basics of PHP

Comment: Yeah i am new to php, studying about 15 days...
I fixed all the errors 

Thanks a lot for your help !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your `php` is not being rendered by your web engine. It needs to have a *.php extension and be on a server that handles it.

Comment: Technically the pages don't _have_ to end in .php as you can easily configure a web server to parse any extension as a PHP file.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it has to do with the multiline

```
             echo "<table border = '1'>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>";
```

Perhaps you try this:

```
echo <<<END
<table border = '1'>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>
```

END;

Comment: not true. As long as the quote is open, you can do multiple lines with an echo

Comment: Plus if that were the case it would error out, not render everything including the PHP.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with the issue in hand.